# Vertical scrollbar for a listview within an expander

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a grid(user-control) as follows with rows 1:5 being an `Expander` which holds a `ListView`, however my attempts to get the Vertical scrollbar for the `ListView` within the Expander have not been successful.

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition> <!--Expander with ListView-->
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition> <!--Expander with ListView-->
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

The `Expander` with the `ListView` is as below, I also attempted enclosing the `Expander` within a `ScrollViewer` but then the sizing of the collapsed header takes up all the space

```
<Expander IsExpanded="True"
          Background="#1F4762"
          BorderBrush="#1F4762"
          Foreground="#FFEEEEEE"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Visibility="{qc:Binding '$P.View.Count > 0 ? Visibility.Visible: Visibility.Collapsed', P={Binding AListCVS}}"
          BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
    <Expander.Header>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="5"
                       FontSize="14"
                       Width="200">
                <Run Text="A Listers : " />
                <Run Text="{Binding AListCVS.View.Count, Mode=OneWay}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
    </Expander.Header>
    <Expander.Content>
    <ListView 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              AlternationCount="2"
              Style="{StaticResource aCompareTemplate}"
              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ATemplateSelector}"
              x:Name="lview"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AListCVS.View}"
              Visibility="{Binding }">
    </ListView>
    </Expander.Content>
</Expander
```

The list template is as follows

```
 <Style x:Key="aCompareTemplate"
    TargetType="ListView">
<!--Control Template-->
<Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid Grid.Row="0"
                  MinWidth="900"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Background="#D4E3F4">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="400"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="200*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Column="0"
                        Height="30">
                    <TextBlock Text=""
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="1"
                        Height="30">
                    <TextBlock Text=""
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="2"
                        Height="30">
                    <TextBlock Text="A Data"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="3"
                        Height="30">
                    <TextBlock Text="B Data"
                               FontWeight="Bold"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"></ItemsPresenter>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Any pointers are much appreciated.

Comment: Usually the problem with Scroll is due to the container in which it is inserted allow infinite size, and therefore it does not appear. Possibly you can correct this by setting a `MaxHeight` to your `Grid.Row`, or to your `ListView`

Comment: What's the parent element of the UserControl with the Grid?

Comment: @CelsoLívero Setting the MaxHeight on the Listview solved the problem

Comment: @mm8 It is a tab control(content)

Comment: @CelsoLívero you should post your "answer comment" as a actual answer so this question can get answered !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the problem with Scroll is due to the container in which it is inserted allow infinite size, and therefore it does not appear. Possibly you can correct this by setting a MaxHeight to your Grid.Row, or to your ListView.

**Edit.:** *as was suggested by @FelixD. and as my above comment helped to solve the problem I am putting it here so the question can be marked as resolved.*